# setInterval and clearInterval not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I have this function which acts as a loading box using `setInterval` to change the background images which creates a flashing effect.

```
 function loading() {
    clearInterval(start);

    var i = 0;
    function boxes() {

        in_loading = ".in_loading:eq("  + i + ")";
        $(".in_loading").css("background", "url(images/load_bar_green.png)  no-repeat");    
        $(in_loading).css("background", "url(images/load_bar_blue.png)  no-repeat");        

        if(i == 3) {
            i = 0;
        } else {
            i++;
        }

    }
    var start = setInterval(function() {
        boxes();
    }, 350);
}
```

But even with `clearInterval` if I click on it more than once the flashing goes out of order. I tried removing the boxes, hiding them but I can't seem to get the 'buffer' cleared? Any ideas?

Comment: `clearInterval` and `setInterval` are javascript functions not jquery. jquery is framework that sits on top of javascript.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it keeps flashing is because every time `loading` gets called it creates a new variable `start`, so `clearInterval` is actually doing nothing. You also shouldn't have the `boxes` function within `loading` because it is doing the same thing, creating a new `boxes` function every time `loading` is called. This will add a lot of lag the longer the script executes.

```
var i = 0;
var start;
function loading() {
    clearInterval(start);

    start = setInterval(function() {
        boxes();
    }, 350);
}

function boxes() {

    var in_loading = ".in_loading:eq("  + i + ")";
    $(".in_loading").css("background", "url(images/load_bar_green.png)  no-repeat");    
    $(in_loading).css("background", "url(images/load_bar_blue.png)  no-repeat");        

    if(i == 3) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: It was perfectly find to have the `boxes()` function inside the loading function.  There was no need to move it outside and doing so pollutes the namespace more than required.  The key to solving this was moving the i and start values to a higher scope.

Comment: Well ideally you would have everything within one namespace or in a closure so the global namespace isn't polluted. To me this way is easier to understand and cleaner

Comment: I was just saying that the OP had `boxes()` inside of `loading()` and you moved it outside to the top level scope.  That part of your change was not required and is not desirable and doesn't make it cleaner.

Comment: Its just a personal preference. I won't put a function within a function unless the inner function is returning something. The global scope will not get polluted because all of this should be in a namespace or a closure.

Comment: OK, I have a different personal preference.  I don't put functions at a higher scope than needed.  If they're only used within a function, then I declare them there.  I think it makes the code more self documenting too since the way the code is declared shows that `boxes()` is a local function not called from anywhere else.  I don't know why a return value has anything to do with your choice.

Comment: I guess the reason why I do this is because, correct me if I'm wrong (maybe a link?), the inner function will be recreated every time `loading` is called?

Answer (score 1):

Function declarations get "hoisted" to the top of their scope, this is what is messing the execution order. Check this: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

The reason is every time you call loading it creates a new Interval or new `var start`. So if you click it twice, then you have two things manipulating the same data. So you need to have the `var start` outside of the function and the `clearInterval` inside. So every time you call loading it clears the interval and creates a new one.

```
var i = 0;
var start;
function loading() {
    clearInterval(start);

    start = setInterval(boxes, 350);
}

function boxes() {

    in_loading = ".in_loading:eq("  + i + ")";
    $(".in_loading").css("background", "url(images/load_bar_green.png)  no-repeat");    
    $(in_loading).css("background", "url(images/load_bar_blue.png)  no-repeat");        

    if(i == 3) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

maybe you should take a look at this Jquery Plugin , it seems to manage intervals very well .

[Jquery Timers Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers)